# Check if a JSONPath string is valid in C#

Tags: c#, json, jsonpath

I am looking how to see if a JSONPath string is actually valid. I have tried with NewtonsoftJSON SelectToken() passing to it a bunch of random data, but it returns null, the same as if a valid JSONPath expression did not match any elements. I thought it might throw an error but it does not.

I need to know whether the actual JSONPath is actually valid, not whether it can return elements or not.

I saw this post: [Is it possible to validate a JSONPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922494/is-it-possible-to-validate-a-jsonpath-expression) but it did not help me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Json.NET Schema to validate json schema.
or you can use deprecated way like this example:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonValidatingReaderAndSerializer.htm

Comment: I am not understanding how this relates to validating a JSONPath string. I dont need to validate my actual JSON, just the JSONPath string that will be used to query the JSON.